# Firebase web reset password with standard reset link not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

From my Firebase web, I am calling the below code to send reset email:

```
firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(this.state.email).then(function() {
    this.setState({ error: "Password reset email sent"});
}.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {
    this.setState({ error: error.message});
}.bind(this))
```

I received the below email:

```
Hello,

Follow this link to reset your myappname password for your xxxxxx@xxxx.xxx

https://myappname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=resetPassword&oobCode=5BQI4oEXwbDg_3RD8mkAA73Nh0KIxoSbutkkigGCBD0AAAFftKBr2A&apiKey=AIzaSyBrBHyYC7QCSnwpHkKuWkAImvKcnjdCKZs

If you didn’t ask to reset your password, you can ignore this email.
```

The reset link is taking me to standard password change page and asks me to enter a new password. After entering it, it says

```
Password changed
You can now sign in with your new password
```

but in actuality, when I login with the new password it says `invalid password`.

Comment: I just tested the flow and it is working fine. Are you sure you are entering the same password? Also make sure the project you are signing in to, is the same one used to reset the password.